# Twitter Login Authentication in ASP.NET: 410 Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am implementing twitter login authentication for my website in asp.net.

After clicking on Twitter Login button and Authorizing App I am getting following Error Page:

`The remote server returned an error: (410) Gone.`

Here is my code:

`.ASPX Page:`

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgTwitter" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/TwitterSigning.png" OnClick="imgTwitter_Click" />
```

`.CS Page`:

```
private void GetUserDetailsFromTwitter()
{
    if (Request["oauth_token"] != null & Request["oauth_verifier"] != null)
    {
        imgTwitter.Visible = false;
        tbleTwitInfo.Visible = true;
        var oAuth = new oAuthTwitter();
        //Get the access token and secret.
        oAuth.AccessTokenGet(Request["oauth_token"], Request["oauth_verifier"]);
        if (oAuth.TokenSecret.Length > 0)
        {
            //We now have the credentials, so make a call to the Twitter API.
            url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.xml";
            xml = oAuth.oAuthWebRequest(oAuthTwitter.Method.GET, url, String.Empty);
            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.LoadXml(xml);
            XmlNodeList xmlList = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/user");
            foreach (XmlNode node in xmlList)
            {
                name = node["name"].InnerText;
                username = node["screen_name"].InnerText;
                profileImage = node["profile_image_url"].InnerText;
                followersCount = node["followers_count"].InnerText;
                noOfTweets = node["statuses_count"].InnerText;
                recentTweet = node["status"]["text"].InnerText;
            }
        }
    }
}
protected void imgTwitter_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    var oAuth = new oAuthTwitter();
    if(!Request["oauth_token"] == null)
    {
        GetUserDetailsFromTwitter();
    }
}
```

`AppCode/oAuthTwitter.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

namespace oAuthExample
{
public class oAuthTwitter : OAuthBase
{
    #region Method enum

    public enum Method
    {
        GET,
        POST,
        DELETE
    } ;

    #endregion

    public const string REQUEST_TOKEN = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
    public const string AUTHORIZE = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";
    public const string ACCESS_TOKEN = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";
    private string _callBackUrl = "oob"; // your app link or any other link...

    private string _consumerKey = "";
    private string _consumerSecret = "";
    private string _oauthVerifier = "";
    private string _token = "";
    private string _tokenSecret = "";

    #region Properties

    public string ConsumerKey
    {
        get
        {
            if (_consumerKey.Length == 0)
            {
                _consumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerKey"];
            }
            return _consumerKey;
        }
        set { _consumerKey = value; }
    }

    public string ConsumerSecret
    {
        get
        {
            if (_consumerSecret.Length == 0)
            {
                _consumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerSecret"];
            }
            return _consumerSecret;
        }
        set { _consumerSecret = value; }
    }

    public string Token
    {
        get { return _token; }
        set { _token = value; }
    }

    public string TokenSecret
    {
        get { return _tokenSecret; }
        set { _tokenSecret = value; }
    }

    public string CallBackUrl
    {
        get { return _callBackUrl; }
        set { _callBackUrl = value; }
    }

    public string OAuthVerifier
    {
        get { return _oauthVerifier; }
        set { _oauthVerifier = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the link to Twitter's authorization page for this application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The url with a valid request token, or a null string.</returns>
    public string AuthorizationLinkGet()
    {
        string ret = null;

        string response = oAuthWebRequest(Method.GET, REQUEST_TOKEN, String.Empty);
        if (response.Length > 0)
        {
            //response contains token and token secret.  We only need the token.
            NameValueCollection qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(response);

            if (qs["oauth_callback_confirmed"] != null)
            {
                if (qs["oauth_callback_confirmed"] != "true")
                {
                    throw new Exception("OAuth callback not confirmed.");
                }
            }

            if (qs["oauth_token"] != null)
            {
                ret = AUTHORIZE + "?oauth_token=" + qs["oauth_token"];
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Exchange the request token for an access token.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="authToken">The oauth_token is supplied by Twitter's authorization page following the callback.</param>
    /// <param name="oauthVerifier">An oauth_verifier parameter is provided to the client either in the pre-configured callback URL</param>
    public void AccessTokenGet(string authToken, string oauthVerifier)
    {
        Token = authToken;
        OAuthVerifier = oauthVerifier;

        string response = oAuthWebRequest(Method.GET, ACCESS_TOKEN, String.Empty);

        if (response.Length > 0)
        {
            //Store the Token and Token Secret
            NameValueCollection qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(response);
            if (qs["oauth_token"] != null)
            {
                Token = qs["oauth_token"];
            }
            if (qs["oauth_token_secret"] != null)
            {
                TokenSecret = qs["oauth_token_secret"];
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Submit a web request using oAuth.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="method">GET or POST</param>
    /// <param name="url">The full url, including the querystring.</param>
    /// <param name="postData">Data to post (querystring format)</param>
    /// <returns>The web server response.</returns>
    public string oAuthWebRequest(Method method, string url, string postData)
    {
        string outUrl = "";
        string querystring = "";
        string ret = "";


        //Setup postData for signing.
        //Add the postData to the querystring.
        if (method == Method.POST || method == Method.DELETE)
        {
            if (postData.Length > 0)
            {
                //Decode the parameters and re-encode using the oAuth UrlEncode method.
                NameValueCollection qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(postData);
                postData = "";
                foreach (string key in qs.AllKeys)
                {
                    if (postData.Length > 0)
                    {
                        postData += "&";
                    }
                    qs[key] = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(qs[key]);
                    qs[key] = UrlEncode(qs[key]);
                    postData += key + "=" + qs[key];
                }
                if (url.IndexOf("?") > 0)
                {
                    url += "&";
                }
                else
                {
                    url += "?";
                }
                url += postData;
            }
        }

        var uri = new Uri(url);

        string nonce = GenerateNonce();
        string timeStamp = GenerateTimeStamp();

        //Generate Signature
        string sig = GenerateSignature(uri,
                                       ConsumerKey,
                                       ConsumerSecret,
                                       Token,
                                       TokenSecret,
                                       CallBackUrl,
                                       OAuthVerifier,
                                       method.ToString(),
                                       timeStamp,
                                       nonce,
                                       out outUrl,
                                       out querystring);

        querystring += "&oauth_signature=" + UrlEncode(sig);

        //Convert the querystring to postData
        if (method == Method.POST || method == Method.DELETE)
        {
            postData = querystring;
            querystring = "";
        }

        if (querystring.Length > 0)
        {
            outUrl += "?";
        }

        ret = WebRequest(method, outUrl + querystring, postData);

        return ret;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Web Request Wrapper
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="method">Http Method</param>
    /// <param name="url">Full url to the web resource</param>
    /// <param name="postData">Data to post in querystring format</param>
    /// <returns>The web server response.</returns>
    public string WebRequest(Method method, string url, string postData)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = null;
        StreamWriter requestWriter = null;
        string responseData = "";

        webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.Method = method.ToString();
        webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        //webRequest.UserAgent  = "Identify your application please.";
        //webRequest.Timeout = 20000;

        if (method == Method.POST || method == Method.DELETE)
        {
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            //POST the data.
            requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
            try
            {
                requestWriter.Write(postData);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                requestWriter.Close();
                requestWriter = null;
            }
        }

        responseData = WebResponseGet(webRequest);

        webRequest = null;

        return responseData;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Process the web response.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="webRequest">The request object.</param>
    /// <returns>The response data.</returns>
    public string WebResponseGet(HttpWebRequest webRequest)
    {
        StreamReader responseReader = null;
        string responseData = "";

        try
        {
            responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream().Close();
            responseReader.Close();
            responseReader = null;
        }

        return responseData;
    }
}
```

}

I have oAuth.css also in App_Code folder.

Any ideas how to fix 410 Error. Is it something to do with retired API v1.0? If so how to resolve it in my scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change the URL in your code to use the 1.1 version of the API since the 1.0 version of the API is dead.

```
url = "http://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.xml";
                               ^^ -- this
```

Comment: I changed it to 1.1 as you suggested but got this error: `The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.`